# Not able to get json response with REST call but CURL getting response

Tags: java, json, rest, curl

This is my curl command with request posted and json response.

```
 curl --verbose \
>   -X POST \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   -H "ABC-Reply-Wait-Time-In-ms: 30000" \
>   --data '{"mobileNo":"xxxxxxxxxx","message":"Your One-Time Password code is {OTP} (OTP Ref = {REF}) {SMSTIME}"}' \
>   --basic --user username:Password \ {URL}

* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /TOPIC/abc_PT_GTY/otpRequestQ HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic zxfsvdcbchdbdbcbc==
> User-Agent: curl/2.90.0
> Host: abcd:9999
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> ABC-Reply-Wait-Time-In-ms: 30000
> Content-Length: 102
>
* upload completely sent off: 102 out of 102 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 57
< Content-Type: application/json
< Server: abc/3.9.0.28
< Set-Cookie: qasw=wertyuie492ef90d3; Path=/
< ABC-Client-Name: #rest/client/10.201.93.21/67542/wertyuie492ef90d3
< ABC-Message-ID: ID:10.128.196.7865b7765f3a1d2gb0:25
< ABC-Timestamp: 12345678987654
< ABC-User-Property-breadcrumbId: topic_abc_PT_GTY_otpRequestQ_null
< ABC-User-Property-CamelJmsDeliveryMode: 2; type=int32
<
* Connection #0 to host abcd left intact
{"status":"success","message":"OTP Sent","otpRef":"QAKQ"}[abcdev@bdslideltsop005 usr]$
```

For rest service method is

```
private StringBuilder getServiceResponse(String request, HttpURLConnection con)
            throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(request);
        wr.flush();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            logger.info("response from generate.otp.service: " + sb.toString());
            System.out.println("" + sb.toString());
        } else {
            logger.info("response from generate.otp.service: " + sb.toString());
            sb.append(con.getResponseMessage());
        }
        return sb;
    }

private HttpURLConnection createConnection(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ProtocolException {
        URL object = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic"+ encoding);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        return con;
    }
```

This is SMS service, when using curl command, getting proper response as shown above but while using REST service call from code not getting Json response back eventhough getting sms on mobile ....

Please help to sort it ... Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: _"using REST service call from code not getting Json response"_ <- so what are you getting?

Comment: *using REST service*: What makes you think that the service is actually following the REST architecture model? Because it is using HTTP to transport requests to a server? SOAP does the same thing ...

Comment: Is your `Authorization` header working that way? Because for basic authentication you normally have to [base64 encode the credentials](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html).

Comment: @vstm,HttpResult is 200 and Service sending sms to mobile when hit it, but not getting json response back this part  "line = br.readLine()" is null

Comment: @Phil, i am getting "line = br.readLine()" is null...

Comment: I have also used HttpClient, but still getting the same response